# Solr: import only certain fields from JSON file

Tags: json, solr

I have several JSON files in this structure:

```
{
  "book" : {
    "truncated" : "true",
    "title": "This is a very long book title and theref"
    "full_title" : "This is a very long book title and therefore it is truncated"
  }
}
```

Or it can look like this:

```
{
  "book" : {
    "truncated" : "false",
    "title": "This is a very short title"
  }
}
```

I want to import these files into Solr 7.4.0. My schema.xml has this definition:

```
<field name="booktitle" type="string"/>
```

Now, when I import data, I want to always take the contents of `full_title`, if `truncated` is true, otherwise `title`. What would be the correct mechanism to do it?

Comment: How are you importing data now?

Comment: Just as suggested by the default solr configuration.

Comment: Which of them? Are you posting data to an endpoint, to the `extract` handler, do you use DIH or are you submitting them with a Solr library?